# How to stop browser settings from changing the font-size in the web App

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, sass, web-frontend

I have a web app where, in the style sheet some of the elements (say 'div') will have font-size specified and some might not. So my problem here is when I change the font-size from the browser, it just enlarges the fonts for those elements where I havent specified the font-size. So Now becoz of this behaviour I have to add the font-size attribute in the scss for every element that I create which is so annoying.
So is there any better way to get this problem fixed. Thanks in advance... [image]

[image]

Comment: Once you'll override my browser settings, I'll navigate away from your site, and will never come back. In practice, what you want is a virus.

Comment: On the other hand, it should be trivial to force a page to show a specific font size. That property is inherited throughout the document tree, and setting `html {font-size: 18px}` (px or any valid absolute unit will do) will be respected allover the document, there's no need to add a font-size to all elements nor any reason to access the browser settings.

Comment: lol thats not my intention, my style sheet is really big so its really cumbersome for me to give stylings for all elements

Comment: ya but I use variable sizes in different pages

Comment: so any workaround for that

Comment: Then use `em` units for the variants, that way the variants are always related to the top most absolute font-size.

Comment: I made [a snippet](https://jsfiddle.net/t9xfjzsv/1/) for you, you can test how the browser settings are effecting to the font size. Add some different types of elements to the page, change the setting. At least in Firefox there are indeed some elements which are resized according to the browser settings, input type of range included (but was not affected in Chrome).

Comment: Thanks where can I check the snippet?

Comment: If you don't yet use a css reset stylesheet, make your life easier, and pick a one to use, without any purpose to promote anybody's work, [here's an example](https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/), I use [this one](https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css) on my sites, and you can find more ...